Counting homomorphisms from $S_n$ to a $p$-group
There are plenty of exercises and questions counting homomorphisms between groups.
However, the following has not been asked yet and I can not see any way to count the homomorphisms using the common techniques.
So, let $n\geq 1$ be an integer and $G$ be a $p$ group for some prime $p$.
Question.
How many homomorphisms can we find from $S_n$ to $G$?
Special case. Let's take $p=3$ and $k=3$. Say $f$ a homomorphism between the two groups. In this case, $\ker f \in\{\mathsf{Id}_n,S_n,A_n\}$. If $\ker f=\mathsf{Id}_n$, then $S_n$ is embedded to $G$, so $n!\mid 3^3$ from Lagrange. Thus $n=1$ and $f$ is trivial. If $\ker f = S_n$, then $f$ is trivial. And if $\ker f=A_n$, then a $C_2\cong f(S_n)\leq G$ and so $2\mid 3^3$, contradiction.
Now, if $p^k$ is any prime power, working as above, as we need $n!\mid p^k$, which means $n=1,2$ and if $n=2$, then $2\mid p^k$ which can work if $p=2$.
So, how can we count in the general case?

Please focus on one question and share your efforts to solve it.

The even more general problem "if $G$ is a group, what are the homomorphisms $S_n \to G$?" is still feasible to understand. Try thinking about what the kernel of such a homomorphism could be...

As indicated, I modified my question, thanks for your comments.

If $n!\mid p^k$ then $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Indeed, thanks, added.

I cannot understand your problem. You know there are three possible kernels. Each kernel is trivial to deal with: what's holding you back?

Let me help then! If $p=2$ and $n=2$ then how we exclude the case that the kernel is non-trivial? Same for the argue to exclude that the kernel is not $A_n$.

Note that $1\neq N\triangleleft S_n$ implies that:

$N=S_n$ (for any $n\geq 2$); or
$N=A_n$ (for any $n\gt 3$; $A_2$ is trivial); or
$N=\{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ and $n=4$.

So:
If you have a one-to-one homomorphism from $S_n$ into a $p$-group, then we must have that $S_n$ itself is a $p$-group. The only possibility is $n=1$ (when $S_n$ is trivial) or $n=2$ (when $S_n$ is cyclic of order $2$). In the former case, there is a unique homomorphism from $S_n$ to $G$. In the latter case, the number of homomorphisms is equal to the number of elements of order $2$ in $G$. This is zero when $p\neq 2$, and at least $1$ if $p=2$, the precise number depending on the structure of $G$.
If the kernel is all of $S_n$, then there is a unique homomorphism from $S_n$ to $G$.
If the kernel is $A_n$, then the image is cyclic of order $2$, so again you have zero maps when $p\neq 2$, and the number of elements of order $2$ in $G$ when $p=2$.
Finally, if $n=4$ and the normal subgroup is the one listed in 3 above, we have that $S_4/N$ has order $6$. Thus, a morphism with kernel $N$ would result in an embedding of a group of order $6$ into a $p$-group... which is impossible.
In summary:

Let $G$ be a $p$-group and $n\geq 2$. The number of morphisms $\varphi\colon S_n\to G$ is equal to the cardinality of the set
$$\bigl\{ g\in G\mid g^2=1\bigr\}.$$

